# How unique_ptr can use the custom deleter function?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

For educational sake I am trying to understand a bit how smart pointers works with custom deleters. So I've written this code on my own that simulates how `std::uniqe_ptr` works. In fact I also think about changing the deleters template functions into template function classes and specialize one for dynamic arrays. Anyway this is what I've tried:

```
template <typename T>
void Free(T* p)
{
    std::cout << "Free(T*): Freeing memory of a dynamic object...\n";
    delete p;
}

template <typename T>
void Del_It(T* p)
{
    std::cout << "Del_It(T*): freeing memory of a dynamic object...\n";
    delete p;
}

template <typename T, typename Deleter=void(*)(T*)>
class Uniptr
{
public:
    Uniptr(T* = nullptr, Deleter = Free<T>);
    virtual ~Uniptr();
private:
    T* ptr_{nullptr};
    Deleter delPtr_{nullptr};
};

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
Uniptr<T, Deleter>::Uniptr(T* p, Deleter d) :
    ptr_(p),
    delPtr_(d)
{
}

template <typename T, typename Deleter>
Uniptr<T, Deleter>::~Uniptr()
{
    delPtr_(ptr_);
    delPtr_ = nullptr;
}

int main()
{

    Uniptr<int, void(*)(int*)> upi(new int(9), Del_It<int>);

    std::cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

- It looks that it works fine but I need your advice, tips... Thank you

Comment: This question sounds like it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it doesn't ask anything in particular, instead you're asking for general feedback on the quality of the code.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest custom deleter can be everything. Let's make a dirty our hand,

```
int main()
{
  auto f = [](FILE* f){std::fclose(f); std::cout<<"I am closing file\n";};
  std::unique_ptr<FILE,decltype(f)>fptr{std::fopen("test.txt","w"), f};
}
```

What we have done here? We have wrapped the file handling in C via `unique_ptr`.
What we get it? In case of forget to close the file after the operation, we ensure that it will be closed automatically.

So that, do not think that custom deleter can only use to delete pointer. I can be specified for any application such as a socket, file, etc...

Please check that [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Code was taken from [File Wrapper](https://github.com/necatiergin/cpp-kursu-kodlar/blob/main/unique_ptr/file_wrapper_01.cpp)

Comment: Did you mean `std::fclose(f);` and `std::fopen`?

Answer (score 1):

A custom deleter can used to perform some *custom clean up operation* when the unique pointer is destroyed. In your case you're not doing anything apart from deleting the pointer. Therefore you're not performing any custom clean up. Plus you've got two functions `Free` and `Del_It` that do the same thing. If `Del_It` is meant for dynamically-allocated arrays, it should do `delete [] p`.

Suppose you're working with legacy code that specifically requires you to call a `release()` function that frees resources:

```
class LegacyClass
{
    ...
    void release() {...}
    ~LegacyClass() {...}
};
```

You can't change the legacy code (it might even be in shared library), but you have to call the `release()` function. So you could define a custom deleter to do that:

```
struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(LegacyClass *ptr) const
    {
        if (ptr)
        {
            ptr->release();
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
};
```

With a unique pointer the deleter is actually part of the type:

```
unique_ptr<T, Deleter>
```

but for a shared pointer the custom deleter is not part of the type; it's passed into the constructor. The custom deleter can be defined as:

- functor
- function pointer
- lambda
- `std::function` *

*(this one can bloat the size of your unique pointer)